# Is DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR limitation in dealing with characters which are > 1 byte

Tags: sql, oracle11g, ora-06512

```
create table t ( x int, y clob );

create or replace procedure p( p_x in int, p_new_text in varchar2 )
    as
    begin
            insert into t values ( p_x, p_new_text );
    end;
    /

exec p(1, rpad('*',4002,'*') );

exec p(2, rpad('é',4002,'é') );

select x, dbms_lob.getlength(y) from t;

select x, dbms_lob.substr(y,4000,1) from t where x = 1; -- this one does not give error and function correctly finds 4000 characters as each character 1 byte

select x, dbms_lob.substr(y,4000,1) from t where x = 2; -- function not able to find 4000 characters and gives error as é is more than 1 byte.
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

Question is what to use from oracle to find 4000 characters when there can be some characters in the clob field which occupy more than 1 byte.

Answer (score 4):

The problem isn't really the `substr` function. It is rather the maximum length of a `varchar2` in SQL: 4000 *bytes*!

That means than even this statement will fail:

```
select x, dbms_lob.substr(y,2001,1) from t where x = 2
```

That is true since 2001 characters of two bytes is 4002 bytes, which is more than the data type can handle. For these cases, you should use `clob`.

Comment: Question is can dbms_lob.substr really determine 4000 characters in a clob column or not 

To add for the example above even this query fails as the substr function is not able to identify where 4000 limit is crossed.

select x, dbms_lob.substr(y,1500,1) from t where x = 2;

How can be that handled if not with substr?

Comment: Yes, it counts characters. Didn't you count them to be 4000? ;) Check for 1 character and you will see. It goes wrong when representing it as a `varchar`, not the substringing itself.

Comment: FYI, under 21c

select index_name, column_position, column_expression, dbms_lob.substr(sys_dburigen(index_owner, index_name, column_position, column_expression, 'text()').getclob(),32767,1) as ce
from all_ind_expressions
;

Answer (score 0):

FYI, under 21c

```
select index_name, column_position, column_expression, dbms_lob.substr(sys_dburigen(index_owner, index_name, column_position, column_expression, 'text()').getclob(),32767,1) as ce
from all_ind_expressions
;

UOM_UNIQUE_LONG_NAME    1   UPPER("UNIT_OF_MEAS_NAME")  UPPER("UNIT_OF_MEAS_NAME")
UOM_UNIQUE_SHORT_NAME   1   UPPER("SHORT_NAME") UPPER("SHORT_NAME")
```

At 32768, it returns NULL.
So it depends on the EXTENDED attributes for string.